# 8K command line restriction when publish typescript from VisualStudio

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a typescript project in Visual Studio that compiles and runs well from the IDE.

When I try to publish it in Azure, VS launches tsc and puts all files to compile in one command line. I have about 130 .ts files. Having average file length about 85 (full path), my command line exceeds 8K an is being truncated so tsc receives incomplete file set and raises errors.

To check that the problem is in 8K, I created Subst drive and shorten all paths. Tsc compilation was OK during this test.

Can anybody help me to workaround the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the the command line arguments as a file e.g. `tsc @sometFileThatContainsTheArguments.txt`. That overcomes any command line limits

PS: This is a trick that grunt-ts uses as well btw

Comment: I did not found ways to ask msbuild to put the file list in separate argument file. It seems the only way I can do it is to make custom deployment script or utilize grunt.